# What is the ll X switch for on my PCI Network Interface Card?

Tags: networking, network-adapter, switch, pci

What is the ll X switch for on my PCI Network Interface Card?
It is an old card from before 2005 i think.

[image]

Comment: It's probably to switch between using straight patch leads or if you're using cross-over cables to connect the card to the network...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a cross-over toggle switch.

In the ll position, the connection is straight through, as in a connection to a switch or router.

In the X position, the transmit and receive pairs are "crossed" or transposed for connection directly to another PC or uplink port.

Without knowing the exact make and model of card I can't be sure, but this likely only effects one port and not all of them, typically the one closest to the switch. (Speculation without knowing more information)

In modern network cards/chipsets, the transceiver handles this automatically, in older network cards or chipsets, it had to be done manually, via a toggle switch, special port on the device, or a cross-over patch cord.